# String doesn't compare

Tags: android, json, string, compare

I have a method where i compare two string, but they dont compare the right way. For example I have this:

```
dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {

            String selectedRate = data[i];
            if (!data[i].equals("")) {

                showSubQuestion(selectedRate);
            } else {
                selectedRate = "";
            }
```

where data[i] is also and string and then it continues to:

```
showSubQuestion(String selectedValue){
...
```

String selectedValueId = selectedValue;
            if (selectedValueId.equals("2459") && selectedValueId.equals("2460")) {

```
            surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[i].getQuestion_order_id().equals("2");
            myTextViews[j].setText(surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[1].getText());
        }
        if (selectedValueId.equals("2461") && selectedValueId.equals("2462")) {

            surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[i].getQuestion_order_id().equals("3");
            myTextViews[j].setText(surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[2].getText());
        } else {
            surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[i].getQuestion_order_id().equals("4");
            myTextViews[j].setText(surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[3].getText());
        } 
}
```

where selected value is ex: 2461 but it doesnt enters i the secont IF.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's part of the JSON:

```
"question_choices":[
{
"id":2459,
"label":"10 - highly likely",
"value":"10"
},
{
"id":2460,
"label":"9",
"value":"9"
},
{
"id":2461,
"label":"8",
"value":"8"
```

Comment: `selectedValueId` can't be two different values at the same time.

Comment: You need || instead of &&.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String selectedValueId = selectedValue;
        if (selectedValueId.equals("2459") || selectedValueId.equals("2460")) {

            surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[i].getQuestion_order_id().equals("2");
            myTextViews[j].setText(surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[1].getText());
        }
        if (selectedValueId.equals("2461") || selectedValueId.equals("2462")) {

            surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[i].getQuestion_order_id().equals("3");
            myTextViews[j].setText(surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[2].getText());
        } else {
            surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[i].getQuestion_order_id().equals("4");
            myTextViews[j].setText(surveyArray[0].getQuestions()[3].getText());
        } 
}
```

Replace this code & Try this out it will work

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are incorrect

```
if (selectedValueId.equals("2461") && selectedValueId.equals("2462"))
```

you should replace && with ||

Your value can't be 2461 AND 2462 at the same time

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to use || instead of &&